# How to echo href with php function inside?

Tags: php, href, echo

How to echo this:

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url');?>/tryme.css">';
```

Am I doing right? It gets an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Please help. THank you.

Comment: what is it that you try to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 8):

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/tryme.css">';
```

`echo` is a function, which prints its argument. You can actually call `echo` like this: `echo("hello");`, which is syntactically identical to `echo "hello";`

if you are calling `echo`, you are already in php mode (ie: there's an open `<?php` somewhere before your `echo` call), so there's no need to enter php mode again for the `get_bloginfo` call. `get_bloginfo` returns a string, so you can just concatenate its output with the rest of your `echo` parameter.

Comment: no problem - can you mark the question as answered by my response? I think that's how this site works :)